# Where is the class lib for Symfony2 widgets?

Tags: forms, symfony, widget

I am trying to use Symfony2 form widgets (e.g. sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice()) but cannot find where the library is to "use"...

Any ideas would be appreciated.

--- Mike

Comment: Look in vendor directory, Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType, but if you want to see the code browse API [docs](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/ChoiceType.html)

Comment: Hi Djuro. Thank you for your response. Indeed I can find form classes in Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType.  However I'm looking for what I assume is a set of add-on classes including sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice().